# Как удалить метку о удалённой ветке?

Tags: git, git-remote

Есть удалённое GIT хранилище (original). Есть локальное хранилище (Z) без рабочих файлов. В локальное хранилище Z были сохранены две ветки branch1 и branch2.

Создали две рабочие папки хранилища.
Из одной выполнили команду удаления удалённой ветки:

```
$ git push Z --delete branch1
```

Теперь, если во второй рабочей папке вывести список удалённых веток, то мы увидим метку branch1:

```
$ git branch --remote  
z/branch1  
z/branch2  
origin/HEAD -> origin/master
```

Если мы из второй папки попытаемся выполнить команду удаление ветки branch1, то получим сообщение об ошибке:

```
$ git push Z --delete branch1
error: unable to delete 'branch1': remote ref does not exist
error: failed to push some refs to 'Z:\GitRepositories\Storage1'
```

Как удалить информацию о удалённой ветки branch1 из второй рабочей папки?

Comment: А что выдает `git branch` (без флагов)?

Comment: @DmitriySimushev одна строка: `*master`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуйте во второй копии обновить *remote* **Z** с опцией *--prune*. это должно удалить информацию об уже несуществующих ветках:

```
$ git remote update Z --prune
```